# Please help me solve this actionscript 3 Error 1067

Tags: actionscript-3

Please help me correct my mistake. I received this Error:

> 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type of void to an unrelated  type flash.display:MovieClip.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var vidLc:MovieClip = null;
var vidLc1:MovieClip;

//--Play Count MovieClip
function countingPlay():void
{

    vidLc = new CountingVid();
    //--
    vidLc1 = vidLc.play();
    //--
    addChild(vidLc1);
    vidLc1.x = -1.80;
    vidLc1.y = 2.10;
}

//-- stop count MovieClip
function countingStop():void
{
    if (vidLc){
        vidLc1.stop();
        removeChild(vidLc1);
        vidLc = null;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your posted code, that error comes from this line :

```
vidLc1 = vidLc.play();
```

Here you are using the [`MovieClip.play()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#play()) function on your `vidLc` MovieClip (`vidLc.play()`), which did return nothing, to initialize your `vidLc1` MovieClip, and that's why the error #1067 is fired, but in the case where you've overridden that function in your `CountingVid` class, then it should return a MovieClip object.

Hope that can help.